# Using the same table, and attributes to return different types of people

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am wanting to create a query that returns a parent and its guardian using the follow tables. My question is how can I use the name attribute in the person table twice to return the name of the caregiver and the name of the parent. Any example code would be appreciated thanks. I know I haven't explained it very well as but if anyone understand what I mean feel free to edit the above. More specifically I want to use only the person table to store information about parents and their children and use display the name of each who are related. How can I do this with a single table.

[image]

Using some advice provided, I was able to create the query but due to a problem with my table it doesn't work. I am using the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
personID INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50),
address VARCHAR(70),
phone VARCHAR(15),
email VARCHAR(30),
year INT,
PRIMARY KEY (personID)
);

CREATE TABLE Guardian
(
parentID INT NOT NULL,
childID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (parentID, childID)
FOREIGN KEY (parentID) REFERENCES (personID),
FOREIGN KEY (childID) REFERENCES (personID)
);
```

What statements should I use where to get this to work properly. I think the problem is that both foreign key statements are referring to the same key in the person table. How do I refer to the same attribute when looking for both the parent and child without getting any errors.

Comment: What you're looking for are [SQL aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: @mgibsonbr: yes I have read some stuff on W3 schools about aliases but I can't see how they could be of any use in this situation. Examples?

Comment: Be careful using w3schools. They are not an authoritative organisation and some of the information on their pages is incorrect or misleading. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools#Criticism

Comment: @batsta13: What error do you get? Can you post the error message?

Comment: 'batemsj1_Guardian' doesn't exist. All create table statement have been issued correctly so theorectically it should work

Answer (score 3):

You can join with a table twice, but you must use different table aliases.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Child.name,
    Parent.name
FROM Person AS Child
JOIN Guardian
ON Child.personID = Guardian.child
JOIN Person AS Parent
ON Parent.personID = Guardian.parent
```

Comment: I have an error. I have posted more information in question. Are you able to provide a remedy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what u are looking for, anyway Try this:

> **select p.name,p.name from person p where p.personid in (select 
>   distinct parentid from guardian )**